# jline problems with escape character in completion

Tags: java, jline, jline3

I am working on a project with jline version3 in java but in completion, I need to have "else if" but it puts \ to escape space as an escape character and I don't have any escape character also I tried `null` instead of a `char[]` but it crashes with null pointer exception

also, I checked https://github.com/jline/jline3/issues/173

Error is:

```
        at org.jline.reader.impl.DefaultParser$ArgumentList.escape(DefaultParser.java:383)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl$MenuSupport.update(LineReaderImpl.java:4403)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl$MenuSupport.next(LineReaderImpl.java:4317)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.doMenu(LineReaderImpl.java:4471)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.doList(LineReaderImpl.java:4614)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.doComplete(LineReaderImpl.java:4149)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.expandOrComplete(LineReaderImpl.java:3875)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readLine(LineReaderImpl.java:585)
        at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readLine(LineReaderImpl.java:443)
        at REPLReader.readLine(REPLReader.java:99)
        at Compiler.getInputCode(Compiler.java:24)
        at CompilerMain.lex(CompilerMain.java:75)
        at CompilerMain.compile(CompilerMain.java:15)
        at Main.main(Main.java:59)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using JLine builtin completer `StringsCompleter` and `DefaultParser`.

If you have completion candidate that have space character(s) then either

1. space chars are escaped if `defaultParser.escapeChars != null`
   or
2. completion candidate will be quoted if `defaultParser.escapeChars == null`.

That is how `StringsCompleter` is supposed to work.
See [StringsCompleterTest.java](https://github.com/jline/jline3/blob/master/reader/src/test/java/org/jline/reader/completer/StringsCompleterTest.java) methods: `escapeCharsNull()` and `escapeChars()`.

NPE is fixed in commit [68a9c1f](https://github.com/jline/jline3/commit/8ae798f09d6d409df79f8fbd963784bf068a9c1f). You should use JLine version 3.10 or greater.

Comment: thanks, but I use RegexCompleter, and when I set escape chars to null program crashed with exception added to question

you can see REPLReader.java in https://github.com/radinParsaei/Compiler/blob/master/repl/src/main/java/REPLReader.java

Comment: NPE is fixed in commit [68a9c1f](https://github.com/jline/jline3/commit/8ae798f09d6d409df79f8fbd963784bf068a9c1f).
You should use JLine version 3.10 or greater.

Inside RegexCompleter you are using StringsCompleter. So in completion spaces are escaped or candidate will be quoted (if escapeChars=null)

Comment: I have created a ticket [jline3#567](https://github.com/jline/jline3/issues/567). The fix will be included in the next release.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but another question is if I need to remove both of quoting and character escaping because `else if` can't be quoted

Comment: The next relaese of JLine will work as you requested when you set `parser ` `escapeChars` as an empty `char` array.